# How to not initialize CSS3 animation when launching another one or visiting another page?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would like to know how to avoid the keyframe animation to be automatically reseted after launching anoher one or visiting another tab of my browser.

```
@-webkit-keyframes play1 {
            0% {
              -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0);
            }
           50% {
              -webkit-transform: translate(-60px,0) rotate(-1080deg) scale(1.5);
           }
           100% { 
               -webkit-transform: translate(-120px,0) rotate(-2060deg) scale(1);
           }
        }
.play1 {         
    -webkit-animation-name: play1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play2 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-60px,0) rotate(-1080deg) scale(3);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-120px,0) rotate(-2060deg) scale(1);
    }
}
.play2 {         
    -webkit-animation-name: play2;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

On this example, if i launch the animation `play1` then `play2` by adding the respective classes on the elements, the position of the element accoding to the `play1` animation is automatically reseted to its initial position (if i visite another tab and come back, all my elements are in their initial position), how to avoid this?

Even worse on mozilla, the animation is reseted when its over.
I don't have this behavior by using the `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` property, but i just want to play it one time.

Answer (score 0):

The property which enables this is: `animation-fill-mode: forwards`